# Simple HTML input onkeypress event not working

Tags: javascript, function, textbox, event-handling

I'm new here (and to web development in general), and I have been trying to understand why my function is not being executed on the specified event.

I found this post, and it seems exactly like what I want, but even this did not work:

[html <input type="text" /> onchange event not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290442/html-input-type-text-onchange-event-not-working)

Any help would be appreciated. My exact code follows. I have some text input fields (actually search boxes), and ultimately I want to have it check a checkbox when the user enters data into the text fields, but it doesn't even seem to call the function.

I have tried a few variants while reading the post mentioned above. Here are some input field attributes I have tried:

```
<input type="date" name="dt" size="10" value="2012-07-21" onChange="SetCheckBox('d')" />
<input type="search" size="10" name="sl" value="" onChange="SetCheckBox('n')" />
<input type="search" size="10" name="sf" value="" onkeypress="SetCheckBox('n')" />
<input type="search" size="20" name="st" value="" onkeypress="SetCheckBox(this);" />
```

and here is my javascript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    Function SetCheckBox(id) {
        alert (id.value);
        document.write('test');
    }
</script>
```

I have tried not passing any arguments and just doing a document.write, but it doesn't seem to be calling the function. And yes, javascript is enabled and working elsewhere on the page just fine!
The script is in the body, just below the form.

The (lack of) behavior is the same in multiple browsers.
Thank you for any help you can provide.
Ray

Comment: Why did you write `Function` with a capital?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For javascript the `function` keyword is lowercase.

```
Function SetCheckBox(id)
```

needs to be:

```
function SetCheckBox(id)
```

Also, you're not passing object to get an id, so...

```
function SetCheckBox(id) {
        var ele = document.getElemenyById(id);
        alert (ele.value);
        document.write('test');
 }
```

Comment: NEVER do document.write after page has rendered

Comment: Thanks... I knew it was something minor. And the code I had within the function was just bogus to test whether it would do something. I used a couple of different methods, which is why I had the id.value (which is how the other page showed it, when passing 'this').

Answer (score 1):

Several issues apart from the already mentioned uppercase F in Function

1. your function passes a variable called id but expects a field
2. you pass a string that is not an ID and not referring to a field
3. only the last version using (this) will work, but there is no value to alert
4. document.write will WIPE the page and all scripts on it when it is invoked after page load (e.g. not inline)

So code should be EITHER

```
function SetCheckBox(id) {
    var val = document.getElementById(id).value
    alert (val);
    document.getElementById('someContainer').innerHTML=val;
}
```

OR

```
function SetCheckBox(fld) {
    var val = fld.value
    alert (val);
    document.getElementById('someContainer').innerHTML=val;
}
```

---

Based on your description, my guess is you want to do this: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/8FuXh/)

```
<input type="date" id="dt" name="dt" size="10" value="2012-07-21"
onkeypress="SetCheckBox(this)" />
<input type="checkbox" id="dtChk" />
```

using this script

```
function SetCheckBox(fld) {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById(fld.id+"Chk");
    // check if something is entered, uncheck if not
    checkbox.checked=fld.value.length>0; 
}
```

and maybe even with this addition

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("dt").onkeypress();
}
```

which will check the box if the field is not empty at (re)load time

Comment: That's pretty much what I want... :) Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

in javascript function keyword is written in small letters and here you wrote F in caps.

Answer (score 0):

onkeypress and onchange event should works

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function SetCheckBox() {
    alert("1");
}

</script>

<input id = "test" value="" onkeypress="SetCheckBox();" />

<input id = "test1" value="" onchange="SetCheckBox()" />

</body>
```

Comment: Not related to the problems in the question and don't use `&lt;` in your code