# how to send value to javascript from input field

Tags: javascript, html, validation

i need to send the input fields  "data-validation" to javascript function.

form is

```
 <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"  data-validation="length" onchange="validate(this);" required />
```

Javascript is

```
 function validate(value)
    {
        var value=value.value;
        var validation=value.data-validation;
        alert(value +"  "+ validation);
        return false;
    }
```

i can't get the value of data-validation in javascript.

Comment: avoid using same names for the parameters and variables             var value1 =value.fname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please review this code 
`getAttribute()` is used to get attribute of element

```
function validate(ele)
        {
            var value=ele.value;
            var validation=ele.getAttribute("data-validation")
            alert(value +"  "+ validation);
            return false;
        }
```

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/GgfM3/

Comment: Please explain your answer, don't just post code.

Answer (score 1):

Attribute of an element cannot be accessed just through the dot. You should use "getAttribute("myAttribute")" in javascript and "attr("myAttribute")" with jQuery.

How about using jQuery? The post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290442/html-input-type-text-onchange-event-not-working) suggests that "onchange is only triggered when the control is blurred". The jQuery .on can monitor value changes in the input.

```
$("#fname").on("input", function(){
    var value=$(this).val();
    var validation=$(this).attr("data-validation");
    alert(value +"  "+ validation);
}
```

Check example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NM968/).

Answer (score 0):

You can retrive the Attribute values using the **getAttribute('value')** method.

In you example you can get the value using

```
function validate(data)
    {           
       var dataFromTextbox = data.getAttribute("data-validation")
       alert(dataFromTextbox);            
    }
```